Browser does not store JSESSIONID cookie
I am trying to write an authentication in my REST API app using Spring Security with username and password credentials.
I have custom controller that saves username and password token to SecurityContext. And that SecurityContext saves to SecurityContextRepository.
When I login into app with Postman and then use other api endpoints, it completes successfully. But when I am trying to do the same in browser, I am getting 401 error by using api endpoints after succesful login.
What I noticed: login endpoint response sets header Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=..., and Postman uses it to send when using another api endpoints. I see that header in browser, but browser does not store the cookie (I've checked it in development tools)
example of reponse headers to login endpoint
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 30 Dec 2024 18:28:02 GMT
expires: 0
keep-alive: timeout=60
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=E2AE75224A50A04D4E64790FA8C2AE46; Path=/; HttpOnly
vary: Origin
vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 0

First of all, I setted up my CORS configuration to allow use any headers, methods and credentials. But it did not help.
I've tried to create cookie manually from responses, but every next request returned 401 error.
I've tried to configure cookie secure and http-only attributes, and it didn't help as well.
I've tried to use different browsers but result the same.
Also I added withCredentials: true header to requests from react app, but it didn't help
Apps use same domain (localhost) but different ports (spring: 8080, react: 3000)
CampaignList.jsx
import { List } from "antd";
import axios from "axios";
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router";

export const loader = async () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/campaigns/get";
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                withCredentials: true,
            },
        });
        console.log(response);

        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
};

const CampaignList = () => {
    const campaigns = useLoaderData();

    return (
        <List
            header={<div>Кампании</div>}
            dataSource={campaigns}
            renderItem={(item) => (
                <List.Item>
                    <a href={item}>{item.name}</a>
                </List.Item>
            )}
        />
    );
};

export default CampaignList;

SpringConfig.java
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(
                        cors -> cors
                        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource)
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/create", "/auth/login", "/error").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext
                        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                        .requireExplicitSave(true)
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public StrictHttpFirewall httpFirewall() {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }
}


CorsConfig.java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000/"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

AuthenticationController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(
            @RequestBody SignInRequest signInRequest,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(signInRequest.getUsername(), signInRequest.getPassword())
        );
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
        securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

SecurityContextRepositoryConfig.java
@Configuration
public class SecurityContextRepositoryConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }
}


I suspect that your browser discard the cookie because of missing attributes. Does the browser throw errors in dev tools about that? I would try to set maxAge, Secure and SameSite.

I blogged about Debugging cookie problems and how to diagnose why the cookies might be rejected or not included.

why are you registering your cors configuration using @Configuration and also manually setting it .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource) leading to double setting it. Dont you know what the @Configuration annotation actually does?

also whats the purpose of all this .securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext.securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository).requireExplicitSave(true)) do you actually know what this code does or are you just blindly copy pasting code? This is not even needed

and this is also not needed HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository as this is the default if you read the spring security docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/persistence.html#securitycontextrepository

@Toerktumlare,  my bad that I twiced cors config. I implemented SecurityContextRepository bean to save context between requests because without saving it to repository after succesful authentication I get 401 error to any other api requests I have in app. With implemented repository I don't get 401 error (at least in Postman). Does Spring save context automatically to repository? Do i need to implement it some how and why? I did not get any information from officially docs

As written in docs SecurityContextPersistenceFilter is deprecated, so I need to use SecurityContextHolderFilter which is only reads the SecurityContext. So I need to explicilty save it https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#requireexplicitsave

If i remove code related to security context repo, login response does not contains JSESSIONID cookie. But I want my auth be persistent between requests. I don't wanna use JWT authentication because I found it more complicated to me.

@v-g, no, I do not see any error related to cookie

What do you think this line does? securityContextRepository.saveContext it explicitly saves your context. If you read the docs it says that if you want spring 5 behaviour you must set requireExplicitSave please explain why you want spring security 5 deprecated behaviour?

Also you write things like ”i get a 401” that does not help us at all there are 20 different reasons to why you can get a 401 and since you have åosted no logs at all we have no idea what your 401 says. You could be doing a bad formatted request, or just have coded things wrong. Remove all the stuff i wrote, enable spring security debug logs and then post logs IN FULL, what happens before the error, the error with full stacktrace
